# Cancel component import in react componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I have a conditionally imported component like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.client === 'abcdf') {
        import('../clients/abcdf/abcdfMenu').then(comp => {
            this.setState({ sideMenu: comp.default });
        });
    }
}
```

Under some circumstances the parent component may be unmounted before the import completes which triggers the warning: `Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

The only suggestions I have found are either don't use async in components or use a `isMounted` property in state (anti-pattern?) or cancel the promise with experimental code not suitable for production.

Do you have any suggestion specifically about dynamic imports? Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having an `isMounted` tracker. It shouldn't be in the state, it can just be a property of the component (i.e. in constructor `this.isMounted = true`, then set it to false in `componentWillUnmount`. It's better to cancel the async action when unmounting, though that can be tricky it certain cases, depending on what kind of async action it is.

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444. I guess the previous solutions I had seen about isMounted were actually talking about a deprecated `isMouted()` method. Just found [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)